# Dynamic db models in golang

Tags: go, go-gorm

I have a yaml file of a certain configuration which is read by the go program to build a struct object.

The struct itself looks like this

```
type YamlConfig struct {
    Attributes map[string]struct {
        Label      string   `yaml:"label"`
        Type       string   `yaml:"type"`
        Presence   bool     `yaml:"presence"`
        Uniqueness bool     `yaml:"uniqueness"`
        Strip      bool     `yaml:"strip"`
        Values     []string `yaml:"values"`
        Default    string   `yaml:"default"`
        Multi      bool     `yaml:"multi"`
        Searchable bool     `yaml:"searchable"`
        Pattern    struct {
            Value   string `yaml:"value"`
            Message string `yaml:"message"`
        } `yaml:"pattern"`
        Length struct {
            Min int `yaml:"min"`
            Max int `yaml:"max"`
        } `yaml:"length"`
    } `yaml:"attributes"`
}
```

I have that map of Attributes that can be anything from "name" to "whatever", that should represent and db table columns with their types.

My question is - can I somehow take that object, which is quite dynamic and may not include the data for all the attributes' properties and convert it somehow into a usable ORM model with Gorm or something?

Should I always define a model struct or is it possible to build structs dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are already using [yaml.Unmarshal()](https://pkg.go.dev/gopkg.in/yaml.v2#Unmarshal) for parsing your yaml config, right?

When you unmarshall yaml into a struct, you can use empty interface instead of complete yaml struct

```golang
var config map[string]interface{}
yaml.Unrmarshal(configFile, &config)
fmt.Println(config["label"])
```

Comment: yes, that looks interesting, but still, I'm not sure if I can create a Gorm model out of it.
I'm thinking of the idea of taking this structure, or just plain yaml and then generate a model for gorm based on the attributes. I'm not sure if this is achievable without generating an actual code of the model first.